# Fraction confidence intervals for small sample size

Tags: confidence-interval, small-sample

What is 95% confidence interval for the fraction of 5 successes out of 12 trials?

Is it possible to compute confidence intervals for a sample of this size?

Comment: There's a fairly good introduction [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Answer (score 9):

It is certainly possible to do this. There are several methods. The literature is surprisingly large; for a good entry point see [Agresti & Coull (1998)](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_coull_1998.pdf)

If you are using `R` you can use this:

```
install.packages("binom")
library(binom)
binom.confint(5, 12)
```

Answer (score 4):

Without the `binom` package, just run the following to get the 95% confidence interval using the "exact" method ([Clopper-Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Clopper-Pearson_interval) method)

```
binom.test(x = 5, n = 12)$conf.int 
# same as binom::binom.confint(x = 5, n = 12, methods = "exact")
```

Comment: Of course, if you prefer a more commonly used (and more frequently updated) R package `Hmisc`, just run `binconf(5, 12, method = "all")`